# How to transform from RTF to SFDT?

Tags: java

I am using Syncfusion Rich Editor, and my data is stored in database in rtf format. And, I need to transform it to sfdt to render it in that React component. How do I transform from rtf to sfdt using java?

I tried with this method that i use to transform from rtf to other formats, but when I use it I get an exception according to known format type.

```java
public static Optional<String> converter(String rtf, FormatType original, FormatType target) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = rtf.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        WordDocument document = new WordDocument(stream, original);

        final String filepath = "output."+target.toString().toLowerCase();
        document.save(filepath, target);
        document.close();
        
        return getFileContent(filepath);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import com.syncfusion.docio.FormatType;
import com.syncfusion.docio.WordDocument;
import com.syncfusion.ej2.wordprocessor.WordProcessorHelper;

public class Conversor {
    
    public static String sfdtToRtf(String sfdt) throws Exception {
        return WordProcessorHelper.save(sfdt, com.syncfusion.ej2.wordprocessor.FormatType.Rtf).toString();
    }
    
    public static String rtfToSfdt(String rtf) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = rtf.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        String sfdt = WordProcessorHelper.load(stream, com.syncfusion.ej2.wordprocessor.FormatType.Rtf);
        stream.close();
        return sfdt;
    }
}
```